# PowerPoint Plugin - Error - HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, pia

I have a problem debugging a project in specific scenario. I'm writing a PowerPoint plugin and when using it with Office 365, it throws following exception

> PowerPointApplication_PresentationOpen - Exception: Error HRESULT
> E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.    Details:
> at
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint.Unadvise(Int32
> dwCookie)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_EventProvider.remove_AfterNewPresentation(EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler
> )    at
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_Event.remove_AfterNewPresentation(EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler
> )    at
> UI.ThisAddIn.?????????????????????????????????????????(EApplication_Event
> , EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler )    at
> UI.ThisAddIn.set_PowerPointApplication(Application WithEventsValue)
> at UI.ThisAddIn.?????????????????????????????????????????(Presentation
> )

Here's the code where its throwing exception

```
   Private Sub PowerPointApplication_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles PowerPointApplication.PresentationOpen
             PowerPointApplication = Pres.Application
    ...
```

Here are the pre-requisite to reproduce the issue

- Office 365
- Create Presentation and Save It
- Now, open presentation using PowerPoint open feature and not from recent.
  and above exception will occur.

I'm using CopyLocal = True. However, when i change Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint setting to "Embed Interop Type" to True and "CopyLocal" to False then it works fine. Can we fix it by keeping CopyLocal property to True?

Comment: You may try using Nuget package: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint/) which according to [here](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/office/) is for Office 2013.

Comment: The note (in the pink box) in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution) may provide a glimpse into why it doesn't work: _...2016 and M365 Apps use the same major version identifier (16.0)..._. While this is written for Access 2016, it may be that this is also true for the other products of the Office suite.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when i change Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint setting to "Embed Interop Type" to True and "CopyLocal" to False then it works fine. Can we fix it by keeping CopyLocal property to True?

This is a good indicator that something is wrong with your interop assemblies. I'd recommend generating new interop assemblies by removing existing COM references and then re-adding new COM references in Visual Studio. Or just download them from the download center, for example, see [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508). There are no newer versions available, so you can generate them in Visual Studio.